# Flex 4 Scroller Step Size

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a `<s:Scroller>` surrounding a `<s:Group>`.  The scroller works, but I want to increase the vertical step size on the scroller.  I've tried everything, but am having no success.  Modifying the `scroller.verticalScrollBar.stepSize` value in the init function seems logical; however, this approach fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to increase the scroller step size? Remove it? A little more detail could help.

Comment: Increase it.  It is scrolling way too slow.  Will edit original post to be more clear, thanks.

Comment: @jimmydugs, Why does modifying the `scroller.verticalScrollBar.stepSize` value fail?

Comment: Not sure why modifying that values fails.  that is part of the problem!  Seems like it should work, in theory.  When I modify that value, the vertical scroll doesn't work at all when I push the down arrow.

Comment: Are you pushing the down arrow on the keyboard or on the scroller?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913721/flex-4-and-scrollbar-stepsize

Comment: Saw that, but was hoping there was a simpler way to modify an obvious property of a scrollbar without subclassing it.  But if that is the only solution, then so be it I guess.  I could also omit Scroller in favor of V/HScrollBars, but that will involve messing with my layout.  Again, I'm just hoping there is a more obvious and simple solution.

Comment: @jimmydugs, I put together a test application and tried to adjust the step size using pageSize, stepSize and a few other properties but had no luck modifying any of the properties. I also ran across this bug report: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-17288. Good luck!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for all the help.  If you want credit, submit this as an answer because you did answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my answer from the comments per the OP's request:

I put together a test application and tried to adjust the step size using pageSize, stepSize and a few other properties but had no luck modifying any of the properties. I also ran across this bug report: [bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-17288](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-17288).

Comment: That link is taking to a restricted page (login required) and the certificate has also expired so it is an untrusted connection. Is there a direct link to your example?

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a workaround, which requires subclassing/extending the skins of the scrollbars.

This way you only have to use a custom scroller, rather then modify each viewport inside the scroller

I put it in the comment on the Flex SDK bug, which clearly should not have been ignored to begin with

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-17288